# Superset Oracle cx_Oracle:Interface Error

Tags: oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle, apache-superset

I'm trying to set up superset 0.36.0 with oracle cx_Oracle 7.3 through docker.
With the create statement, I am getting **oracle error: not a query** and in the
logs it is throwing **cx_Oracle:Interface Error**

I have tried setting `"engine_params": {"isolation_level": "AUTOCOMMIT"}` I thought it may be issue with the commit because if I try creating table with the same name it throws **name is already used by an existing object**

Any suggestion please.

Comment: can you provide the code ?

Comment: isolation_level affects only the way how a transaction behaves in a multiuser environment. Oracle Database issues an implicit COMMIT before and after any data definition language (DDL) statement., so you don't need AUTOCOMMIT for a create table statement

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that you are attempting to fetch from a statement that is not a query. You can only call `cursor.execute()` and cannot call any one of `cursor.fetchone()`, `cursor.fetchmany()`, `cursor.fetchall()` or iterate over the cursor. DDL statements like creating a table, index or view and DML statements like insert, update, delete are all examples of statements that cannot be queried.